# How to fix tooltip not showing for disabled button when hovering

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this button

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#part4" class="btn btn-info tabcontrol mainbutton col-2 offset-8 disabled" id="part3to4" title="Please acknowledge the checkbox before going next" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="top">Next</a>
```

and I have initialized the tooltip:

```
$('#part3to4').tooltip();
```

The tooltip still doesnt show up. How do i change my code in a way that it shows the tooptip when the button is disabled? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forget to include some libraries. To use bootstrap tooltip you need to include Popper.js.

> You must include popper.min.js before bootstrap.js or use
>   bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js
>   in order for tooltips to work!

A possible solution is to your problem is the following. If the `a` html element has a disabled class (so the link is not enabled) you can enable tooltip otherwise no.

Please see the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsogbj41/) I prepared for you.